# How to compare the NSString *

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to compare 2 NSString *. I use the `[[arr objectAtIndex: i]compare: @"compareString"]` . However, it does not work in my program. What wrong of the problems?

Comment: What exactly *does not work*? Do you get an error?

Comment: What is arr? And what do you mean by compare? Just check for equality or dictionary / lexicographic order?

Comment: @taskinoor : `arr` is probably an NSArray or NSMutableArray which contains NSStrings.

@MarkSiu: can you test if `[[arr objectAtIndex: i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` computes to `YES`?

Comment: @Felix King, taskinoor, Bogdan Constantinescu. thank you for your reply. The arr is NSMutableArray * and it stores the NSString * object. @Bogdan Constantinescu, yes, it displays yes.

Comment: I see you have accepted my answer.  Just for my own curiosity, which of the four possibilities was the correct one?  I'm guessing number 2.

Comment: @JeremyP, I guess it is number 4, there are \n at the end of the array, so it cannot be compared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible problems:

1. You have indexed off the end of the array causing a bounds exception
2. The array is nil meaning the compare would always result in equality
3. The object in the array does not respond to compare: causing an unrecognized selector exception
4. The object in the array is not a string causing compare: to fail

If you tell me what actually happens, I'll tell you which of the four possibilities is the issue.